# ansible rotate downloads from get_url

Tags: ansible

I have files downloaded from a CI server using [get_url](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.html).
This is fine, and I use the `backup: yes` option to make sure I can roll back.

However those files are big (~100MB each), and I would like to delete them and keep, say, the last N files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) and [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) modules ?

a rough aproximation of your code looks something like this:

```
- name: find old files
  find:
    paths: "/var/tmp"
    age: "3600"
  register: files_to_delete
- name: delete old files
  file:
    path: '{{ item.path }}'
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - '{{ files_to_delete.files }}'
```

Comment: Not exactly keeping the last N, but that's nice and simple enough that I may use it :)

Comment: True, but its more ansible-ish. If you want you can use the shell command with `- shell: find /var/tmp -name 'blah.txt.20*' | head -n -N | xargs rm -rf` and you can modify the find to match your criteria